# Tag excerpt cuts in the tag page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt, tags-page

In [the tag page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) the excerpt of some tags cut some starting words. E.g. Excerpt of [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) tag is:

> New users are those users who may be new to the Stack Exchange Q&A format, and generally have a low reputation score.

But at present it starts from "those users who..." *in the tags page*.

> [image]

And this doesn't happen with every tags. E.g. Excerpt of [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) tag is perfect.

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I suspect this has to be a bug because the first few words are even missing from the html. So it is not just an CSS glitch. Verified on IE10.

Comment: It could also be by design. It skips 'This tag is for ' and it skips if the first words matches the tag...

Comment: @rene - Yeah it seems like it is by design. I have edited [deleted-users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-users) tag excerpt it also skipped "This tag is".

Comment: Is this what is called 'reversed requirements engineering'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design.

In English only, tag descriptions starting with common prefixes such as "this tag" or "the tag {foo}" are elided when displaying the tag list, in order to convey the maximum amount of information in the limited space allowed in the tag cell.

Comment: **+1** I've always wondered about that...