# Tag overview page cuts off beginning of some descriptions (not just common words)

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202410/353011) says that the descriptions on the tag overview page are meant to cut off common words such as "This tag" at the beginning of the tag description and although I find this weird, it seems to work well for most tags. But in some cases there are also other words cut off.

An especially horrible example is the "minecraft" tag on gamingSE: It starts with:

> "Do not use this tag for Bedrock edition!

That's because a LOT of new users get that wrong (it's honestly a confusing arrangement of tags, especially after Microsoft's renaming of all the variations). And what does the tag overview page show?

> "for Bedrock edition!"

That is exactly the opposite of what this very important sentence is meant to say. Especially the word "not" and other negations should in no case be cropped from the beginning and cropping the word "use" is also debatable.

Comment: Update: The tags have been changed around in a big cleanup project a while ago, so this specific example is no longer the case. Judging by the many upvotes this question is getting recently, there seems to be a new example somewhere. It would be useful if someone commented what it is.